# Apache camel aws-ses - cannot set email address dynamically

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, apache-camel

I am trying to send emails using Apache Camel aws-ses.

This works fine when I hardcode the **to** address, but when setting the to address using a camel header value, I get the following error.

> AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService, AWS Request ID: 24a14170-e812-11e3-86b1-4d4202db06aa, AWS Error Code: InvalidParameterValue, AWS Error Message: Missing final '@domain'

Here is my camel route:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route customId="true" id="timerToLog">
    <from uri="cxfrs:bean:rsServer"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="com.domain.PasswordResetMessage"/>
    <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
    <setHeader headerName="Comments">
        <simple>${body.email}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <log message="The message header contains ${header.usersEmail}"/>
    <to uri="velocity:Welcome.vm"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelAwsSesHtmlEmail">
        <constant>true</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <log message="Just before sending to AWS, the message header contains ${header.usersEmail}"/>
    <to uri="aws-ses://info@domain.com?accessKey=ACCESSKEY&amp;secretKey=itsASecret&amp;subject=Testing&amp;to=${header.usersEmail}"/>
    <setBody>
        <constant>EMAIL SENT with AWS SES ID ${header.CamelAwsSesMessageId}</constant>
    </setBody>
    <log message="And at the end, the header contains ${header.usersEmail}"/>
```

Does anyone know what or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running into the problem of your `<to>` not substituting the dynamic portion of your uri. You may need to use the recipient list EIP per this [camel FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).

Per the FAQ you can try something like this (not tested, you may need to tweak slightly?)

```
<recipientList>
     <simple>aws-ses://info@domain.com?accessKey=ACCESSKEY&amp;secretKey=itsASecret&amp;subject=Testing&amp;to=${header.usersEmail}</simple>
 </recipientList>
```

Comment: Thanks again! The [recipientList](https://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) is one powerful tool!

Comment: True, the Recipient List EIP rocks.